# Calling an AWS signature based API's using karate

Tags: karate

While calling my AWS API's using postman we are able to configure authorization as "Aws signature". Want to implement same with karate, really stuck on to this because the Authorization header is dynamically changing through postman internally, any help on this would be really great.[Postman AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Trg.png)

Comment: we tried to make this possible but never got any feedback. maybe you are the one that can help the community :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019538/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks for the inputs, will try and update here!