Signature generation for multipart file
I have a request where I pass a multipart file. I want to know how the signature is generated for such requests because I keep getting invalid Signature sent error.
 * configure headers = {Content-Type: 'multipart/form-data', signature: 'W9IEv6gUBzeYBUPWDlR6DN7wcFlY0nhoVmZLWg60w=' , Accept-Encoding: 'gzip, deflate, br' , Accept: '*/*' }
And path 'somepath'
And multipart file bill = { read: 'ABC.PDF', filename: 'ABC.PDF', content-Type: 'multipart/form-data' }
When method put
Then status 200
And print response

I have verified that the signature generation process is correct. So is there a different way to generate signature for request with multipart file?
Note: Here, I have generated this signature based on the payload of the previous request.

what do you mean "how the signature is generated" - karate does not do anything of the sort. there are ways for you to do it yourself, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019538/143475 - if that does not answer your question, I have a feeling this is very specific to your environment, so consider contributing code to karate to improve it

looks like it is internal to my organization. I will surely contribute code to karate once it is sorted.
